# Add column from another dataframe if two column matches

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, enumerate

I am working with huge volume of data and trying to map values from two dataframe. Looking forward for better Time complexity.

Here I am trying to match Code from df2 which are in df1 and take MLC Code from df1 if values match.

df1

| Code | MLC Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 |
| 2 | 66 |
| 8 | 62 |
| 4 | 66 |

df2

| Code |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 4 |
| 8 |

Result df

| Code | MLC Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 |
| 2 | 66 |
| 3 | NA |
| 4 | 62 |
| 4 | NA |
| 8 | 66 |

Here is the code I am using to perform this task but it take lot of time to compute.

```
for i, j in enumerate(df2["Code"]):
    for x, y in enumerate(df1["Code"]):
         if j == y:
            df2["MLC Code"][i] == df1["MLC Code"][x]
```

Comment: Iterating through dataframes is an antipattern, you can read more about it in this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/4147687).  You should look at using a merge, join or concat.  The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html) here outline the differences between them, it looks like a merge or join will do the trick for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```py
df2.merge(df1[['Code', 'MLC Code']], how='left', on='Code')
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to reproduce the process...

First import module and data

```py
import pandas as pd

# Your sample data
data_1 = {'Code': [1,2,8,4], 'MLC Code': [8,66,62,66]}
data_2 = {'Code': [1,2,3,4,4,8]}

# Create Dataframes from your data
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2)
```

Use merge

```py
df_out = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='right', left_on='Code', right_on='Code')
```

You will get this output:

```
    Code    MLC Code
0   1        8.0
1   2       66.0
2   3        NaN
3   4       66.0
4   4       66.0
5   8       62.0
```

If you want no Index you can do this:

```py
df_out = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='right', left_on='Code', right_on='Code').set_index('Code')
```

```
    MLC Code
Code    
1   8.0
2   66.0
3   NaN
4   66.0
4   66.0
8   62.0
```

Also... The solution given by @alex does the job!!!!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `cumcount` with `groupby` create he sub-merge key

```
out = df2.assign(key = df2.groupby('Code').cumcount()).\
           merge(df1.assign(key = df1.groupby('Code').cumcount()),how='left')
Out[106]: 
   Code  key  MLC Code
0     1    0       8.0
1     2    0      66.0
2     3    0       NaN
3     4    0      66.0
4     4    1       NaN
5     8    0      62.0
```

Comment: WOW....  Always nice to learn!

Comment: @AndreNevares happy coding ~